# Visual Studio SSRS - Define Query Parameters Window

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

A couple of months ago I created and published over 50 reports.  Each report used a stored procedure that accepted parameters.

Now when I try to create a new report with a stored procedure VS doesn't want to play nice.  Instead of reading the parameters and fields of the stored procedure and populating the corresponding tabs in the DataSet properties, I am now encounting a new window titled "Define Query Parameters".

I even went back tried creating a new report with an old stored procedure (that still works in my old report).

What's changed in VS?  Why is it all of sudden prompting this new window and how do I make it go back to the previous behaviour?

Comment: In my experience, sometimes when a temp table is added to an SP, this can cause this behaviour. Not sure of the mechanics or reason for this, though, or even if this is the actual underlying reason. Any resemblance to your case?

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me sometimes.   I don't know exactly why, but it seems to have to do with Visual Studio needing some dummy parameter values so it can test your stored procedure and get a sample output so it knows what fields to expect.   Maybe it tries some dummy values on its own and if they work it doesn't have to ask you, but if it doesn't, it has to ask you to provide them.

What I do know is that when I get that "Define Query Parameters" dialog box, if I just type in some valid dummy values and click Ok, it works fine, lets me finish building the dataset, and I can finish building the report in peace.

So to summarize:   I don't exactly why, but this isn't a setting that changed in VS.  The potential for it to happen has always been there, but it only happens sometimes, and you just have to deal with it and move on.